# Multi level sub domains as nameserver

Tags: dns

This is just a general knowledge question. Why havent I ever come across any nameservers of this type: ns1.ns.domain.com?

Is it a convention to use only one leveled nameservers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[djbdns](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns.html) does this by default. See for example:

```
$ whois lifewithdjbdns.org

Name Server:C.NS.BSWS.DE
Name Server:A.NS.BSWS.DE
Name Server:B.NS.BSWS.DE
```